# How do you remove duplicate values in array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have an array where each element is the mean of a set of random numbers. I want to be able to remove duplicate values in this array. How would I go about doing this?

So far I have tried:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
    
    for j in array:

        if array[i] == j:
```

and then some operation to remove the element from the array. However, this will just remove every instance of every duplicated element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use np.unique():

```
unique_values = np.unique(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the order of the elements then use the following

```
deduplicated = list(set(array))
```

Answer (score 2):

This way was worked for me ([Ways to remove duplicates from list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-duplicates-from-list/)):

```
res = []
[res.append(x) for x in test_list if x not in res]

# printing list after removal 
print ("The list after removing duplicates : " + str(res))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create the array of a set:

```py
deduplicated_array = list(set(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using a python `set` :)

Example with code:

```py
# set cannot have duplicates
# Output: {1, 2, 3, 4}
my_set = {1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2}
print(my_set)

# we can make set from a list: what you want
# Output: {1, 2, 3}
my_set = set([1, 2, 3, 2])
print(my_set)
```

Then you can use `remove` or `discard` (if you don't want errors upon removing non-existing items):

```
my_set = {1, 3, 4, 5, 6}
print(my_set)

# discard an element
# Output: {1, 3, 5, 6}
my_set.discard(4)
print(my_set)

# remove an element
# Output: {1, 3, 5}
my_set.remove(6)
print(my_set)

# discard an element
# not present in my_set
# Output: {1, 3, 5}
my_set.discard(2)
print(my_set)

# remove an element
# not present in my_set
# you will get an error.
# Output: KeyError

my_set.remove(2)
```

If you prefer to work with a list, then you can then convert back to a list with the `list` function:

```
my_list = list(my_set)
```

Docs: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/